# What cosmic ray sensor is attached to this Balloon?

Tags: nasa, cosmic-radiation, balloons

This short BBC News item shows a very large high altitude balloon lifting a science payload to measure high energy cosmic rays for about 100 days, circling the Earth perhaps twice in the process.

Unfortunately I could not find any reference to the name of the mission or the payload. I'm wondering if there is a website or a map with it's current location as it circles the Earth.

I'm also looking for a short description of the cosmic ray detector itself. The payload looks really small and light, what kind of information can it record? Without a long or deep array, can it measure the angular distribution of the flux?

If each cell in the photovoltaic array is from a 6-inch wafer, I can use that as a scale to estimate the size of the two white "shoe boxes" sticking out on either side of the top of the payload as about 50x50x15 cm. Is this a two-element lateral telescope, looking for coincident detections through both? Can it point itself, or is rotation around the vertical axis random?

---

[**Up, up and away! Nasa's super soaring space balloon**](http://www.bbc.com/news/av/39720835/up-up-and-away-nasa-s-super-soaring-space-balloon)
"This mega balloon - the size of a football stadium - was launched in New Zealand and will float around Earth for 100 days"

Alternate [link](http://www.bbc.co.uk/newsround/39720835).

**Click** (or right-click) images for **large size:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this mission that launched May 7 2017 ended in failure.

[image]

This was billed as the third mid-latitude test flight of a Super-Pressure Balloon.  The payload:

> Flying on this year’s SPB test flight was the International Extreme
>   Universe Space Observatory-SPB payload. EUSO-SPB is a high-energy
>   cosmic ray particle astrophysics payload testing a fluorescence
>   detector and its supporting technologies under the severe operating
>   conditions of the stratosphere.

The balloon developed a leak and controllers brought it down in a controlled fashion after 12 days, 4 hours and 34 minutes aloft.

From [here](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/wallops/2017/nasa-completes-balloon-technology-test-flight)

There is a bit more info on the payload [here](http://jem-euso.roma2.infn.it/?page_id=1055):

> The instrument is an updated version of the first EUSO-Balloon
>   payload. It includes a full original JEM-EUSO PDM (photon detection
>   module with 2304 pixels), as in EUSO-Balloon, and a Fresnel lens
>   optical system, 1 m each side, covering a field of view of ±6 degree.
>   An improved version of the trigger allows to catch high energy cosmic
>   ray events.

and [here](http://astroserve.mines.edu/euso_spb/2017-spb.html):

> The instrument was built by members of the JEM-EUSO international
>   collaboration. It will fly suspended from the super pressure balloon
>   and look down on the atmosphere from suborbital space to record the
>   faint traces of UV light produced by cosmic ray extensive air showers.
>   At its heart is a sensitive Photon Detection Module (PDM) that is
>   mounted at the focus of a custom optics system of UV transmitting
>   fresnel lenses. The lenses are 1x1 m in size. An array of 36 64
>   channel multichannel photomultiplier tubes form the PDM array. The
>   signals of the PDM are digitized with a 2.5 microsecond time exposure.
>   The data acquisition system records "video clips" containing 128 of
>   these images. The field of view of the detector is 11x11 degrees. The
>   recorded “videos clips” will show the trajectories of EASs as they
>   develop in the atmosphere. To improve the contrast of the faint air
>   showers above the night background, each subsection of the PDM is
>   covered by a UV transmission filter. The instrument will operate at
>   night when the moon is down.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for tracking this down - it looks like the original BBC news article was pulled, but I found an alternate that still has the video link. Now I understand the payload is a big, large-aperture, low-resolution near-UV(~350-400nm) downward-looking "camera" for cosmic ray tracks in the atmosphere. It turns out there is or was another one [on the ISS](http://jem-euso.uchicago.edu/instrument.php) as well.

Comment: Yes, I was interested to see that the "camera" is the big box in the center and stares downward! Didn't expect that.

Comment: It looks like the ISS one is maybe going to fly after 2020... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JEM-EUSO

Comment: Some image-stuffed presentation pdfs of the whole project:  [4 MB Euso Balloon a pathfinder
mission for the JEM-EUSO
experiment](https://indico.cern.ch/event/186337/contributions/1457944/attachments/258220/360783/tue_ei9_1450_osteria.pdf) and also [13 MB JEM-EUSO Program
Cosmic Rays at Extreme Energies](https://indico.cern.ch/event/381134/contributions/900602/attachments/759368/1041637/AMS-CERN_Picozza.pdf)